# zscore function in R

Tags: r

I am unable to get the `zscore` function to work. When I try to call it, I get the following error:

```
could not find function zscore
```

The online documentation online states that it is in basic R library.

Searching online reveals that other people had the same problem some time ago - though on macs. Does anyone know how to fix this problem or use other alternative function?

I saw somewhere they were using `scale()`. This works but I am not sure whether it is the correct substitute to "zscore".

Comment: This question is clearly off-topic here and I am surprised that it remained open for all these years.

Comment: @Amoeba The criteria in early 2011 were not quite the same and many R-specific questions were accepted by the community.  Normally we "lock" such old questions, which adds an automatic notice that they are not currently considered on-topic.  To have a lock added, please flag the thread for moderator attention.

Comment: @amoeba the standards will necessarily change over time -- [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/should-we-consider-grandfathering-old-r-and-other-programming-heavy-posts) and [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/should-the-standards-for-closing-questions-be-relaxed-somewhat-for-old-questions) (among others) meta discussion would apply. Additionally in this specific case, with slight modification (to describe what scale() does and what the not-in-vanilla-R zscore() was supposed to do in algebraic terms) it would likely be on topic now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the `zscore` function you are looking for can be found in the R.basic package made by [Henrik Bengtsson](http://www.braju.com/R/), which cannot be found on CRAN. To install use:

```
install.packages(c("R.basic"), contriburl="http://www.braju.com/R/repos/")
```

See [this similar topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3890/2714) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

Also, the base R function `scale()` can be used to produce z-scores. See `help(scale)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following function to calculate the z value:

```
zVal <- round(qnorm(1 - (1 - prob)/2), 2)
```

Example, for 90%:

```
> zVal <- round(qnorm(1 - (1 - 0.90)/2), 2)
> 1.64
```

Comment: -1. This is unrelated to z-scoring a vector of values.